# How can make a json endpoint of a WordPress page including html markup?

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I want to make a JSON endpoint for this WordPress page so I can use this page in other PHP application with HTML markup so by sharing CSS and JS files this page will take same styles as WordPress page.

```
 <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>10 users included</li>
                  <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>20 users included</li>
                  <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Priority email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>30 users included</li>
                  <li>15 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Phone and email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pages you can use the wp-json plugin, which is now included with WordPress. Something like

```
<yoursite>/wp-json/wp/v2/pages
```

Can take reference from :

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/
2. http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/pages/

Comment: Cool, I have figured it out. I have made custom endpoint to my page call so I can now feed in anything I want. :)